# List Index Error on Python

Tags: python, list, function, loops, indexing

Im writing a program to try to calculate how many times the most repeated word in a list occurs. I keep getting an error that says: index error. Even though when I print the list of my word_list, it shows there are 108 elements. Could someone point me in the right direction as to where my error is?

```
  length = len(word_list)
  num = 0
  print(length)

    while num <= length:

            ele = word_list[num]

            if ele in wordDict:
                    wordDict[ele] = wordDict[ele] +1
                    repeat = repeat + 1
                    if repeat > highestRepeat:
                            highestRepeat = repeat

            else:
                    wordDict[ele] = 1
                    repeat = 1

            num = num+1
```

Comment: Where do you define repeat? I think you should use you just `if wordDict[ele] > highestRepeat`

Comment: In `while num <= length:` change `<=` to `<`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List indexing goes from `0` to `length-1`.

In your while loop, you've told the `num` to go from `0` to `length`. That's why you have an index error.

Simply change `num <= length` to `num < length`. That should fix your code for you.

---

As an aside, there are much better ways to do this particular task. A simple two liner:

```
from collections import Counter

print(Counter(word_list).most_common(1))
```

`Counter` will calculate the frequencies of each element in your list for you, and `most_common(1)` will return the element with  the highest frequency in your list.

Answer (score 1):

Just to mention that there is a more compact solution to your problem:

```
word_list =['this' ,'is', 'a', 'test', 'is']

for word in set(word_list):
    print word, ": ", word_list.count(word)
```

Comment: This will print all words and their counts, not the word with maximum count (as the OP asks).

Comment: Correct, Counter is a better solution, answers have crossed. Just wanted to point into the direction of avoiding loops by using a standard python approach.